# passing objects from AsyncThread to Fragment Class

Tags: java, android

```
public SimpleAsyncTask(JSONObject obj, Activity activity) {
    this.obj = obj;
    this.activity = activity;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String...params) {    
    String result = "";    
    return result;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    List<Appointments> lists = new ArrayList<Appointments>();
    return lists;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {

}
```

I call my AsyncTask Thread from MainUI thread. I have a fragment class which has a listView, how would i pass the `List to my Fragment class.`

```
ArrayAdapter < String > adapter = new ArrayAdapter < String > (getActivity(),
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listObject);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make the lists variable a member of your Fragment class, instead of being scoped within your AsyncTask

something like this:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    private List<Appointments> lists = new ArrayList<Appointments>();
    ......
```

then in your AsyncTask, use it as follows:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // Not instantiating it from scratch, but using the class variable
        lists = new ArrayList<Appointments>();
        return lists;
     }
```

Comment: "lists cannot be resolved to a variable..." i get this error in onPostExecute

Comment: If your member variable is in the same class as your AsyncTask, you should be able to resolve this variable (maybe try protected or public scope when you declare the variable?)

Comment: I use this pattern all the time, so I know it is valid.

Comment: Thanks, buts its actully in different class... my AsyncTask and Fragment are two different classes.

Comment: In that case, you will have to create the list in your Fragment, and send it to the AsyncTask as an argument.

Comment: I did that, and passed it to my AsyncTask via the constructor.... now on the onPostExecute i do my calculation... how would i know that the Async Thread is done and my MainActivity class to start its UI work

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27273/discussion-between-kevin-and-booger)